# Kenwood TS-50 and USB to Serial

Tags: kenwood, linux, computer-control

I paired my old Kenwood TS-50 with serial, by using FTDI TTL-232-5V-AJ USB to serial converter. 
I used ideas from here:
http://steeman.be:8080/posts/TS-50%20USB%20Interface/
and here
[http://i.imgur.com/BmYMq2v.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/BmYMq2v.jpg)

I have Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and I can detect my serial to usb converter, by using dmesg:

```
[ 1596.365806] ftdi_sio 1-5:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 1596.365857] usb 1-5: Detected FT232RL
[ 1596.371078] usb 1-5: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

To be sure that I can connect to serial port I first wanted to be sure by checking that connection works with minicom, but it gives me:

```
minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: Permission denied
```

Despite I am in dial out group and I did all that is written here: https://websistent.com/fix-serial-port-permission-denied-errors-linux/

I can temporary solve that by using it with sudo. That I did, but minicom says, that ir is offline.

I also tried rigctl:

```
ffu@ffu-desktop:~$ rigctl -m 201 -r /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 4800 -v
rig_open: error = IO error 
ffu@ffu-desktop:~$ sudo rigctl -m 201 -r /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 4800 -v
Opened rig model 201, 'TS-50S'

Rig command: f
rigctl_parse: input_line: f
get_freq: error = Invalid parameter
```

Its looks like from me that apparently something is wrong at OS level, but what?

Comment: Probably I missed restart - now the "Permission denied" problem is gone.  But I still getting the "Invalid parameter" error with rigctl. :(
Now I am thinking about serial port parameters - are they right...

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/hamlib/mailman/message/34302264/ There was a bug causing a similar error some time ago, I assume you have the latest version of rigctl?  Can you try (or borrow) a different rig to see if you get the same results?

Comment: +1 for doing a good job of summarizing your problem and what you've done to correct it so far.

Comment: I have latest major version: rigctl, Hamlib 3.1. Does the latest minor version 3.3 will change something? I could try different rig but it will not be soon.

Comment: Tried to setup some serial sniffer:
jpnevulator --ascii --tty "/dev/ttyUSB0" --read
But yet no luck - no output at all. :(

Comment: This might have something to do with it: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/02/10/ftdi_says_knockoff_chips_part_of_criminal_operation/

Comment: The intial problem (permission denied) I would guess is because you added yourself to the group, but didn't log out and back in, so your current session didn't have the group permissions.  sudo -g dialout minicom  would fix it without running minicom as root but logging out is probably just as easy.